# My export preview and video doesn't match the timeline in Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

[image][image]I've edited several videos over the last month or so on Adobe Premier Pro and exported them at 1280 x 720 with zero issues.  Now all of a sudden my aspect ratio looks all buggered up when I go to export my video.  Everything will look fine on the timeline but there's a ton of extra space around the video when I preview and export.  Not sure what the heck I did.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Sequence settings, you may set higher resolution that the most of the content is. Also your videos may to not fit well: right click - Set to Frame size.

Answer (score 0):

Your Program Monitor is zoomed in, that's how your timeline actually looks. Reset the scale in the Program Monitor to "Fit"